# django python randomly raise mysql operational error and redis "too many open files" error

Tags: python, mysql, django, redis, fastcgi

I have a web service built with python+django+fastcgi(flup)+mysql+redis.

But it always occasionally raises some exception,
e.g. `OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (24)")` or 
`ConnectionError: Error 24 connecting 10.160.94.231:6379. Too many open files.`

Log files displays as follows:

```
2012-08-19 12:36:36,322 ERROR Internal Server Error: /xxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
  File "/xxxxxx/push_notifi/models.py", line 60, in get_device_token
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis-2.4.12-py2.6.egg/redis/client.py", line 773, in sadd
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis-2.4.12-py2.6.egg/redis/client.py", line 283, in execute_command
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis-2.4.12-py2.6.egg/redis/connection.py", line 260, in send_command
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis-2.4.12-py2.6.egg/redis/connection.py", line 243, in send_packed_command
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis-2.4.12-py2.6.egg/redis/connection.py", line 191, in connect
ConnectionError: Error 24 connecting 10.160.94.231:6379. Too many open files.
2012-08-19 12:38:54,942 ERROR Internal Server Error: xxxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/xxxxxx/users_stat/views.py", line 85, in receiver
    saveUser(user)
  File "/xxxxxx/users_stat/models.py", line 86, in saveUser
  File "/xxxxxxx/users_stat/models.py", line 46, in syncVersionToPushService
  File "/xxxxxxx/utility/db_access.py", line 37, in execNonQuery
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (24)")
```

I think it may caused by some kind of file descriptor leaks, but I use `redis.Redis` to connect redis and set redis connection time out to 100 seconds.

In mysql connection, I called `cursor.close()` and `db.close()` after each query. I really don't know where the fd leak happens.

I also checked `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`, and there is always has enough file-descriptor. like:

```
2272    0   170019
```

Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Try an `lsof` to identify what process is holing these descriptors.

Comment: thx, useful command, i found there are lots of python log records in list.i removed the logging, wish it helps :D.